# Deploying SpringBoot war file to Tomcat results in 404, local host works fine

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-boot

I've been using SpringBoot to develop a webapp - running it on localhost works fine, both using a jar and war to run it from terminal such that:

```
 mvn install && java -jar target/Eeeeek-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

and

```
java -jar target/Eeeeek-1.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.war
```

both work fine, I'm now only packaging as a war file.

The site is visible at `http://localhost:8080`

I'm now trying to deploy it to my tomcat manager hosted by digitalOcean.

visiting the ip of the droplet `http://46.101.2.91:8080` shows the tomcat manager which is great, I then deploy using the manager but encounter errors when I try and access it.

Ideally I'd like the app to eb the landing page of the ipaddress.  Any help is appreciated, thank you.

The url when I click the link in manager is `http://46.101.2.91:8080/Eeeeek%2D1%2E3%2E2%2EBUILD%2DSNAPSHOT/` which doesn't look right...

[image]
[image]

EDIT:  As per the answer given I've deleted the .war and filter from webapps, ran a mvn clean package.  Then used the manager to upload the new shiny war. During the upload the page crashed with an error at URL `http://46.101.2.91/manager/html/upload?org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=846E819F21EFBBE715AFBFA39F349E34`

I returned to the main and found that the app had been uploaded.
Checking webapps dir also confirmed but the same error persisted.

Answer (score 1):

Does your main class extend the good class? It was my problem. Here an example:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DeployTestApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(DeployTestApplication.class);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DeployTestApplication.class, args);
}
}
```

Also I had to add this to Maven

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check Your web apps directory is this war file or any folder

**(Eeeeek-1.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT)** is already there.

if it is so then `delete` it and reinstall using maven or copy the `war` file to the `webapps`  directory and `restart` the `Tomcat`.

If again problem occurs then check ur `web.xml` otherwise another issue what i found in my project deploement was **Major minor version Exception** Problem.

I can't say exactly but u should try these solutions may work for you..

Thanks

Comment: Hi, I tried what you suggested and updated the post, I don't have a web.xml...perhaps because of spring boot.

Comment: is this a MVC Project or a Simple REST Web Service  ? I think web.xml is working as frontcontrollor to the app so You should check  ` Eeeeek-1.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT ` folder. there must be a web.xml I think..
http://www.javabeat.net/spring-boot-spring-mvc/

Comment: Spring Boot with MVC.  There's no web.xml in that folder or any of the sub folders.  first time using spring boot so not exactly sure what's going on.  All of the posts I've read imply that it's all taken care of